# Is there any way to select a column from navigational property on the basis of another column?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am new to Code First in lambda expression. I find it hard to write a query in it.

I have a users class which includes a navigational property named "Initials".

I want to select a `Code` column for an `IntialID` which is foreign in `Users` table but can't properly.

Users class:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public short? InitialsID { get; set; }
    public virtual Initials Initials { get; set; }
}
```

Users DAL:

```
        public User ValidateUser(string Username, string Password)
        {
            return uow.UserRepository.GetQueryable().Where(x => x.UserName == Username && x.Password == Password).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

UsersRepo:

```
        public AbstractRepository<User> UserRepository
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.UserRepo == null)
                {
                    this.UserRepo = new AbstractRepository<User>(context);
                }
                return UserRepo;
            }
        }
```

Initials class:

```
    public class Initials
    {
        public short? InitialsID { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried this:

```
  public ActionResult Login(User model)
    {
        VAILCertificates.DAL.UserDAL userDAL = new DAL.UserDAL();
        VAILCertificates.DAL.Entities.User user = new User();
        user = userDAL.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
        var query= user.Initials.InitialsID.Value.where() 
        if (user != null)
        {
            Session["User"] = user;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Certificates");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username or Password.");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried this => `var query= user.Initials.Code; ` ? because `Initials` is `virtual` navigation property. but remember you have to enable `LazyLoading` for your context

Comment: Try like this => `return uow.UserRepository.GetQueryable().Include(x => x.Initials).Where(x => x.UserName == Username && x.Password == Password).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: It would potentially be helpful to add your repository code to see if there is an issue there.